# shell env variables are not passed in docker-compose using jenkins

Tags: shell, jenkins, environment-variables, docker-compose

To reproduce my issue:

1. Create freestyle project in jenkins with one task 'execute shell' with this code:

> ```
> export PROJECT_NAME=hello
> export IMAGE_NAME=hello-world
> docker-compose -p ${PROJECT_NAME} up
> ```

2. Place docker-compose.yml in job's workspace:

> ```
> version: '2'
> services:
>   app:
>     image: ${IMAGE_NAME}
> ```

3. Run this job.

I get error:

```
Started by user anonymous
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/testenv/workspace
[workspace] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson1988957642163027988.sh
+ PROJECT_NAME=hello
+ IMAGE_NAME=hello-world
+ docker-compose -p hello up
The IMAGE_NAME variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
```

I created script with same code on my mac machine and it works!

```
Alexanders-Mini:deploy alexanderkondaurov$ ./test.sh 
Creating hello_app_1
Attaching to hello_app_1
app_1  | 
app_1  | Hello from Docker.
app_1  | This message shows that your installation appears to be working correctly.
```

I don't understand why it doesn't work in jenkins. 
As you see docker-compose doesn't see shell env variables :(

Comment: docker-compose on jenkins has version 1.7.0 and on my mac 1.7.1

Answer (score 2):

look at the response of Rajiv.
[docker-compose, export environnement variables are not working in Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38992589/docker-compose-export-environnement-variables-are-not-working-in-jenkins)

Copy of the Rajiv response :

Your environment variables inside jenkins shell will not be imported automatically. Add environment variables through .env file under your Jenkins job's workspace.

```
$ echo PROJECT_NAME=hello >> .env 
$ echo IMAGE_NAME=hello-world >> .env
$ cat .env
export PROJECT_NAME=hello
export IMAGE_NAME=hello-world
```

Then run

```
$ docker-compose up
```