# docker-compose, export environnement variables are not working in Jenkins

Tags: shell, jenkins, docker, environment-variables, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose.yml file with differents variables

```
version: "2"
services:

  data:
    image: "${registryUrl}/data:${image_version}"
```

In my shell, I export  registryUrl &  image_version

```
export registryUrl=zhcjie.distribution.ata.com:8652
export image_version=1.0-SNAPSHOT
docker-compose up
```

that's work in my local (I'm using boot2Docker) but it doesn't work in Jenkins. I have a wrong message.

```
The registryUrl variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
The image_version variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
```

I try to pass env variable with EnvInject plugin, it doesn't work too.

Comment: In Jenkins, I have docker-compose 1.7.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your environment variables inside jenkins shell will not be imported automatically. Add environment variables through **.env** file under your Jenkins job's workspace.

`$ cat .env
registryUrl=zhcjie.distribution.ata.com:8652
image_version=1.0-SNAPSHOT`

Then run

`docker-compose up`